# Can a solana send transaction add arbitrary data like a message?

Tags: transactions, message

Is there a way to add a message to a send transaction on solana? And how can this be viewed and what is the max message length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Memo program exists for this purpose. You can:

- use the memo program to produce a log in the transaction
- leave evidence that the memo was approved by up to 12 signers

Regarding the message length; from the docs:

> As of v1.5.1, an unsigned instruction can support single-byte UTF-8 of up to 566 bytes. An instruction with a simple memo of 32 bytes can support up to 12 signers.

Read more here: https://spl.solana.com/memo

Answer (score -1):

There is no feature in core Solana to attach a message to transactions.

However, it can be easily implemented in apps if needed.

Also, the transactions in most apps write message to their log (the log itself is off-chain, though), and standard explorers in the Solana ecosystems display these log messages.

Comment: any examples? how big can these logs grow?